# Webkit console.log reverse order?

Tags: webkit, console

Is there a way in which to get the logs being produced via console.log() in the web inspector to show in reverse order? In this instance, I'm testing for things that produce lots of log messages, but they scroll off the bottom and its super inconvenient. I'm also open to hackish solutions. One I just considered is a setInterval that calls clear() on the console every couple of seconds, but I want to see if there's another way.